# generating heat by vibrations

Tags: thermodynamics

Heat is basically fast moving molecules in all random directions, bumping in to eachother etc.

The idea might be silly, but I was thinking about a vibrating machine you could place in your room, that would generate heat without using any heating elements. Basically a really fast vibrator.

Is it possible to generate heat like this?

Comment: In theory, yes. Just running a fan will heat the room, albeit somewhat slowly without making a lot of noise (not many fans dissipate even 100W, and a 100W light bulb will heat a room, just not that much). A heating element is simple and scales up to high power readily and controllably.

Comment: It's possible, but why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: Also, a macroscopic-sized vibrator would generate relatively coherent motion in the air surrounding it (relative to, say, a heater), so its temperature effect would likely be negligible compared to its noise, which presumably isn't what you want.

Comment: Heat is energy transferred from one system to another due to temperature differences.  Your "fast moving molecules" description is internal energy. Temperature tells us something about internal energy states.  Rub your hands together really fast and see if you can increase their temperature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Basically a really fast vibrator. Is it possible to generate heat like this?

Yes, you can buy one now. It's called a "space heater". Electrons go in one side of a wire and bump into impurities causing the wire to vibrate at the molecular level.

That's pretty much how any heat source works, although they vary in the amount they directly radiate out as light compared to the amount they convect off their surface.

Oh... you mean really large macroscopic vibrations, so you can see them? A fan in a box would do the trick, it *will* heat your room.